# PGP encrypted mails look so awful in the gmail-plain-text-editor

Tags: linux, firefox, email, gmail, pgp

I run Firefox on OpenSUSE 13. 1

I want to send mails to my friend and they are encrypted. But if I use Gmail and switch to plain-text then the mails look so awful  to me. (see below)

And the receiver of the mails—my friend—only receives a bunch of not readable signals. See below:

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----

Version: GnuPG v2.0.22 (GNU/Linux)


hQIOA+sIYy064y0iEAgA5qLfZig2baYG9szZ2m3XJ777nYCU/BIWGd4Lbad2DNDK

TskXNJKr5Ztff19ZesebGZjf/aCH12LBQuTD4EkwHiNNGVGcsfGfk+JU5X7/qI8y

hKrHnkf8Tb2NYabcvqax6oLqP2wjHlnGp5Z36Ic+68amlq68pSI6ffURsoWDaTwm

JqzxbZA+g5iLlMKipDh5JqGE8nhGZJzIofMdKB3Kk3yZUEV/xFoKnVT5nat5lSOC

T0aUyU/WKmbmI6jkkmjFNR4I/H6siigCbnUKZp493pyFXMoIQab+X4jw82FiHEPx

jfvVGCfPdLnd8aNBN+yypni3nLJAUePQSEAO7X5X9ggAh1eBaLT5EZWsR+b7ZtQO

svCGJhkg/U1arFJ8ttAr6bbcoN8hs0NfpVTkzXmQWRnv85kOuUySFrgAEEGIQy1a

PoDH+qmC4DXGSssyKCmFoUyi0IVpR5cTTntn4KmKZWnkYAZCZt1y5DqEtAOmWqiG

ARBICv8rNDGAmK9s4wXdy9fHn25r8VMq40frw6DFAEg8PxrESfFj349iM4OltbN2

0X7ZlK3RKQRjcH3A6NKfdToWuYvbM6TRZ1niqTuuOyLbcxWoIwK7gsIEinOlLsNH

ML6iLXi5Td1vzsDnvI3qWt129CMM8D4+OAL6E77X2Oihqk6EraekWsVdFeA5Ljio

5dLpAZr+HU8OLixYzzCj750GmgVd86dxtZYTSOFNaa9zoCToDYsQTeVHPhS0sbEr

cVW5GJKve7Ke4NV8vOQ9GS9di5g3gXA6XOEv4EdCKcPYiWAGHb2XUY794UeCgDZ2

8h1o9ASjslsgrT/+PWp1Am0sw+9zWH1ox5P0A3ZHkKP8B3jMhvtNLu/XSdKhMMAd

LRJb50qcsb5EsbQHeJ5pEiyHECjz7Rp3WUjpvMhpqOrEYpDzkfP/bvqIjYdQwcd5

fhZQrIcwJIfO7u8UMgYZGOYmIr1qegWCTESGfTiy6hyv2U7uENBVeLK9uK5xl+/Y

EZKvtT8z4+2xB4+E81XeJteJhukso5wq0y8K9h+WfMH+iyYxzxIh1rPpxxQc5r3d

KHtQUFB5e3sTD5vlY0T/QI+6Luq59gBcSq7lYo1TuLCJm/Wkd8PrIPaU3V33r87X

Xmiu5dYM3UJtiougj+DW1Z39vAT1jjro+IS7aGPCMqu/nDgrx9M66ZJf3hAdc/Ga

8kjg3DItnK+4+Jc9ws3QafrbtuwZUWgpWyAmOhSiHn/1ku13EB0JMXgcV4yZ2S+D

kItPx2NRTUWFS6XBWR7kkZ4wHapXMO356guGWKBwDWWI85ItRfsJhncv3xkhSdG3

fsfAMy5tT5odjgYUENlPAIOMETm63R3HNnnaxLCZHdQEO/3BHa6e8Yq3ykhkB1cB

xb7ZunmATo8rxe5NiIiAWkUuix5SczO38vmZu2eAkcgI4ZR9hcUuWWdUGQPPTaxu

o2AcNcyKGF0LPhuemVfHBrlZJcgXpFAtSfAWZFJqST3Devqf3/IqAnyTqrpOdiO5

tIwjGxlbQQA0R6VIJHHcaC+Qa7w7mxIzy0uaMs/MULsYxYbZ6AuzZJOzUJpLT2pC

2E9LfwHLFQqUn5+llXm8bCr/ox0NrhjvUJN2cfIq//Xvd+1813auY2M/HHwgaga0

EfSIPzPv4GkNMco1DrOuaueOssmjIOs0mpz8O053A5oKKzONwY5Ez2pSO8PZ5sWs

pftr7bxs+p9xFmuVmK87lBbUPzjwk0OBbY8yseENu7WzfLOrx+ylFSiEUbpkevV8

B8Oi3PPZKCpKV+05MTjehyz8BB0pSJ9gA1ZarM63D95l1Usk9MtHaFrXrjq+tRB+

v/0Pn33j1pGV1OgyX9yvWoBtST6nykgmlKWKtYCLTJiiNgieAzv3LAlgE2ySz3vg

i5DW6KCdeeva3t9uIDY8fnl9N9LPNndOXeQV8smypVcbyWAlLaMDuD/nuqrKYD97

Tt+tVNDFnWdaKNOWB5xSGO359H9qk4BWubG9Ih2qwcf6NQ==

=C+d1

-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

Comment: Looks like a regular encoded message, nothing wrong as far as I can see. Only your friend needs to decode the message.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are sending mail using safegmail. Suring this the receiver will receive the text in string of gibberish,nonsensical characters. In order to get it decrypted at the receiver end. you have to click the hyper link  "click here to access the mail content".

[image]

The question set during mail sent will be asked to receiver and once answering the answer it will open decrypt page where you can decrypt the mail content by copying the content in to it and clcking "Show My Mail" button.